# Programmatically creating new column in Sharepoint List using Web Services in C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2007

I have new list using AddList function of Lists Web Service.

No i want to add new columns into it.
I tried code given on **Lists.UpdateListItems Method**:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-services/ms772668(v=office.12)

But not getting solution yet. It is simply adding new value to existing Columns.

**Note: Using Web Services. (I am not using Microsoft.Sharepoint.dll)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looking at the wrong MSDN article.

Try **Lists.UpdateList Method** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-services/ms774660(v=office.12).

Comment: I am getting soap exception :(

Comment: Could you add the SOAP exception to your question?